# VBA excel seems unable to read non latin cell values

Tags: vba

My VBA excell application needs to read non-latin cell values:
someString = Cells(1,1).value
when I analyse the hex content of someString, it contains only a sequence of "3F", i.e. question marks.
I need to obtain the original unicode string. When I copy the non-latin cell value into ultra-edit then the information is correctly copied

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/howto-convert-vba-unicode-to-utf8.html)

au crypto website has vba code that does the job